# Pspice ac sweep problem

Tags: electrical-engineering, modeling, simulation, electrical, electronics

I want to run an AC sweep from 1 Hz - 10 MHz and calculate the output of the circuit (the voltage on RL), however spice shows that my voltage is 0 in a lot of parts that it shouldn't. I believe the circuit to be correct since it is copied from a book. I must have misunderstood something because I run into similar problems using the sine source (transient sweep not ac).

[image]

Comment: Where is it showing 0V, where you are expecting an alternate value. Does the values match your analysis?

Comment: The voltage on RL is the main problem, I have to run an ac sweep and find how it's amplitude changes but it is always 0 like my ac source is not working.

Comment: Do you know if the transistors switching on? What voltage are you expecting at $V_{RL}$

Comment: I have no idea why the wouldn't switch on, how do I check? I also try to run an transient simulation with an sine source (50mv 1kHz) but that doesn't work either. The voltage on RL is always 0 ( apart from a few nanoseconds in the start of the simulation where it's unstable, but I don't think that counts)

Comment: Did you delete the previous post? Take a look at the datasheet for the transistor to figure cutoff. active and saturation regions for the transistor. Here is the datasheet for [BC238](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/105081.pdf) Also take note the BC238 transistor is tag obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a missing ... Wire from top R5 and collector of BC238.
However, gain seems low ... -35 dB from 10 Hz to 200 kHz. Adapter for high voltage piezo or same.